# Can Firefox's debugger find the function which is accessed by a javascript: URL?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have found a website which, when a button is clicked, runs a JavaScript function by URL. I can view the function in the Debugger but when I try to call it by name from the console, I'm told it's not defined. Is there any way in the Firefox debugger to find the full package name or context of the function from the javascript: link, so I can know what to type at the console?

Comment: It's unlikely we can help  you without showing us specific details about your situation.  For example, what does "runs a Javascript function by URL" even mean?  What does that URL and code look like?

Comment: Please explain what is meant by "runs a javascript function by url".

Comment: http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme ; clicking on an "add to bag" button runs the URL "javascript:addBricks(x,y)" but addBricks cannot be called from the console and there seems to be no way to search for its context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [mozilla (developer):](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)

> This is the first place to go when you're debugging a web page; open the Web console using the Web Console option in the Web Developer menu. This shows any JavaScript errors in your app, as well as any logging calls from the console API.

Browser Console

> The Browser Console lets you see all JavaScript errors and logging in the browser, including from Firefox code. To enable it, go to about:config in the url bar and set devtools.chrome.enabled to true, or set the "Enable chrome and add-on debugging" option in the developer tool settings. Activate it through with the menu Tools > Web Developer > Browser Console.

You can also start the Browser Console when you launch Firefox, by launching Firefox from the command line and passing `--jsconsole` as a flag:

```
/path/to/firefox --jsconsole
```

Log to the Browser Console using the standard console API after importing Console.jsm:

```
let console = (Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm", {})).console; 
console.log("Hello from Firefox code");
```

There is tons more on the website click link above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can view the function in the Debugger, create a break point inside the function. The next time the function runs, execution will be paused at your break point. To find the function's context, type `this` in the console window.